# Transpose dataframe with ID and measures that repeat in n rows

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe that looks like this:

|  | ID | Oct-22 | Nov-22 | Dec-22 | Jan-23 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John Doe - ABC |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | measure1 | 421 | 421 | 421 | 421 | ... |
| 4 | measure2 | 312 | 312 | 312 | 312 | ... |
| 5 | Apple |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | measure1 | 421 | 421 | 421 | 421 | ... |
| 7 | measure2 | 312 | 312 | 312 | 312 | ... |

How do I make it so the format is something like:

|  | ID | MMM-YY | measure1 | measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe - ABC | Oct-22 | 421 | 312 |
| 2 | John Doe - ABC | Nov-22 | 421 | 312 |
| 3 | John Doe - ABC | Dec-22 | 421 | 312 |
| 4 | John Doe - ABC | Jan-23 | 421 | 312 |
| 5 | Apple | Oct-22 | 421 | 312 |

There's also a lot of NaNs, unsure if that's messing with the attempts I've made so far.

Tried to transpose rows, fill NaNs with zero, etc. I appreciate any help.

data generation code:

```py
data = {
    'ID': ['John Doe - ABC', 'measure1', 'measure2', 'Apple', 'measure1', 'measure2'],
    'Oct-22': ['', 421, 312,'', 421, 312],
    'Nov-22': ['', 421, 312,'', 421, 312],
    'Dec-22': ['', 421, 312,'', 421, 312],
    'Jan-23': ['', 421, 312,'', 421, 312]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

numbers are just examples

Comment: looks like the dataframe is constructed incorrectly. Can you post the dataframe generation code?

Comment: sorry about that, I think most recent edit displays the tables in markdown correctly now

Comment: Can you post the dataframe generation **code**?

Comment: added sample python code for dataframe generation

Comment: What Roman means is that, while you **can** transform the shown dataframe into the expected output, it would be much better to create the desired output directly. How did you create the input in the first place?

Comment: Your constructor doesn't match the table. Are the headers correct or as first row?

Comment: sorry yes, original was based on Excel but I've updated the table shown and the constructor to match. no original input generation code, it was generated from manual data entry over years

Comment: @harry so you never have empty rows?

Comment: @mozway no empty rows, data always comes in the three row format of:
an identifier name (multiple strings together random)
measure1 (not the actual measure name)
measure2  (not the actual measure name)

there may be a 3-row bundles where there are IDs, but no values for measure1 or measure2 across the columns

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what you are trying to achieve. I came up with this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = (
    pd.read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/q/77091747/5183623")[0]
    .drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0", "..."])
)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df['measure'] = df['ID'].str.extract(r'^(measure[0-9]+)$')
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.extract(r'^(ID[0-9]+)$').ffill()
df.dropna(subset=['measure'], inplace=True)
df = df.melt(['ID', 'measure']).rename(columns={0: 'MMM-YY'})
df = df.pivot_table(values='value', index=['ID', 'MMM-YY'], columns='measure')
df.columns.name = None
df = df.reset_index()
df
```

Output:

|  | ID | MMM-YY | measure1 | measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID1 | Dec-22 | 6453 | 1245 |
| 1 | ID1 | Jan-23 | 2134 | 3456 |
| 2 | ID1 | Nov-22 | 241 | 532 |
| 3 | ID1 | Oct-22 | 421 | 312 |
| 4 | ID2 | Dec-22 | 6453 | 1245 |
| 5 | ID2 | Jan-23 | 2134 | 3456 |
| 6 | ID2 | Nov-22 | 241 | 532 |
| 7 | ID2 | Oct-22 | 421 | 312 |

Answer (score 0):

The desired logic is unclear. Assuming that you cannot fix the original input directly and that the correct input is the dictionary, you can reshape using:

```
# identify IDs based on prefix
m = df['ID'].str.startswith('ID')

# reshape
out = (df.assign(col=df['ID'],
             ID=df['ID'].where(m).ffill())[~m]
   .rename_axis(columns='MMM-YY')
   .set_index(['col', 'ID'])
   .stack()
   .unstack('col')
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    ID  MMM-YY measure1 measure2
0  ID1  Oct-22      421      312
1  ID1  Nov-22      241      532
2  ID1  Dec-22     6453     1245
3  ID1  Jan-23     2134     3456
4  ID2  Oct-22      421      312
5  ID2  Nov-22      241      532
6  ID2  Dec-22     6453     1245
7  ID2  Jan-23     2134     3456
```

If you really have the column headers as first row, first run:

```
df = (df.iloc[1:]
        .set_axis(df.iloc[0], axis=1)
      )
```